# Which one is more possible to waste less memory, one big memory manager or several small one?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, memory-management, probability

First of all, this may be more like a math problem.

I am writing a module that requires memory piece by piece and never release it until its instance is dead, so I write a simple memory manager to reduce `malloc`. The memory manager requires a block of memory during initialization, and the size of memory block is controllable by user, then the manager pass the memory pieces to user when required. If the manager is running out of memory, it doubles its memory block size by `realloc`. At the end, we can figure out that relation between required memory size and the total wasted memory size is:

```
f(x) = 2^k - x, 2^(k-1) < x <= 2^k
```

Now I have several memory users, I can either create a memory manager for each of them (the overhead of manager is not worth to consider), or create only one memory manager and share it among all users. The number of users and the size of each user's usage of memory may vary in a great range. So, which strategy have greater possible to waste less memory?

---

The memory manager does hide the actual memory block position and provides offset to user, to avoid `realloc` issues. The interface is quite simple:

```
void *memo_ref(Memo memo, MemoOffset offset)
{
  panic(offset < memo->used, "invalid offset is passed to memo");
  return &memo->memory[offset];
}
```

So I think the compiler will inline it and there's no difficult about optimization.

And also, there's no need to worry about data race, since all users of the manager come from the same thread. They just require in a staggered way.

In my opinion, one big manager leads to faster program, since there are less `realloc` which is a big cost. So my focus is on memory usage. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should try to ask it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Please be aware that [crossposting is prohibited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Reallocating the memory pool with `realloc` means that the addresses of existing allocations may change. That makes it impossible to use a pointer to (or into) an allocation. Alternatives exist (offsets from the pool start, for example) but they are expensive.

Comment: @rici On modern CPUs, pool offsets are not expensive at all.

Comment: It is not clear how one memory manager would improve the memory consumption. Wouldn't you simply end up with an array of pointers to various segments, making the solution identical? If the single memory manager only allocates one big chunk of data, then that's probably not going to end well, as the call to `realloc` will block the access of all items until done. So if item "x" causes the handler to run out of memory, item "y" will be blocked from accessing its data until realloc is done. You get a tight coupling between unrelated instances, bad idea.

Comment: @kuba: using an offset means that you need to also pass the base around, in some fashion, which adds a cost to API design and complicates cross-API calls. It also may make it more difficult for the compiler to find optimisations. These costs may not be enormous but they certainly exist, and they need to be measured against the benefits, if any.

Comment: @rici I have explained a few more things by editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work anyway: `realloc` is not guaranteed to succeed in resizing in place - it's free to allocate a larger block and copy all the data into the larger block. I presume that the users expect the data to stay at fixed addresses.

The simplest way to address this issue is not to use the C library, but use the platform-specific virtual memory APIs to reserve a large chunk of address space, then commit memory to it on demand. E.g. on Windows, you'd use `VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_RESERVE, 0)` to reserve the needed contiguous address space, and then `VirtualAlloc(addr, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)` to commit the pages as your used memory area grows. **This means that you're at most having just *one extra page* per memory pool**. If you stick to small (4k) pages, this means that there's **never more than 4092 bytes wasted** per pool (one word short of a page).

Furthermore, on 64-bit systems, there's no need to pass the addresses using a base+offset: the reallocations won't ever realistically run out of address space, so there's no need to move the mapped view of memory within the virtual address space. You can use plain pointers/references!

There are benefits to having a separate memory area for each user: it improves the locality of reference - the user's data is close together, and thus improves cache performance at all levels, including the page swapper should paging out occur.

In a 64-bit application, reserving large address spaces for each user is not an issue and has minimal overhead. E.g. you can reserve 1Gbyte for each user. It is worth reserving say twice the largest area a user may need.

In a 32-bit application, if the address spaces needed are large, the users may need to cope with having their data moved within the address space. This can be achieved by remapping the pages and thus doesn't need to copy anything. Taking a sensible assumption of there being a 64-bit OS backing the application, you may benefit from mapping the memory area to a file. This lets you completely unmap it from the address space without losing the contents, and those contents don't have to hit the disk either - the OS will cache them if it can. Thus you can grow the address space for a user without having to copy anything and without wasting the smaller address space during a grow operation: first unmap the smaller view of the file, then map the larger view of the file. The user will need to cope with being given a new starting address for the memory area. The user may refer to the memory by adding offsets to a base address: this performs well enough and allows the flexibility of a movable address space.

Comment: "it improves the locality of reference - the user's data is close together, and thus improves cache performance at all levels"  It also leads to better OO design, so I would say this is the best method regardless of memory consumption.

Comment: The question is edited. Any help from math view would be grateful to accept.

Comment: @Cowsay My whole point is that  using memory mapping (`VirtualAlloc` or `mmap`) you're at most wasting **one page**. Never more! I hoped it'd be more obvious. There's no "math" to it. At any point, you overallocate one page per memory pool and that's that. And no, having one area for all users doesn't help at all: whatever gains you may have from simpler memory allocation will be lost from the fallout from poor locality of reference and thus poor cache utilization (at all levels - i.e. on systems lows on RAM your program will waste more time waiting for page-ins and page-outs).